# Illumination Effect Removal

Tags: image-processing

is there any method of removing effect of illumination from an image.

The illumination effect is causing bad effect on segmentation

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4632174/5987

Comment: If you're referring to thresholding, take a look at adaptive thresholding

Comment: The effects from "illumination" can be numerous. Without further explanation or an exsample of the problem you're facing this question is way to vague.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project for medical images and according to some articles that I studied I found the uniform LBP, as a way for removing illumination effects
hope this be useful for you